# Is there a PowerPoint to PDF converter outside of Microsoft Office?

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, powerpoint, document-converter

I need to convert a `.pptx` file to `.pdf` but I don't own a copy of Microsoft Office.  I tried OpenOffice, but my document was badly flawed in OpenOffice and so much was lost.

Is there a tool out there to do this conversion without having to actually go and buy a copy of Microsoft Office?

Comment: Would you be willing to use a web app?

Comment: If they don't do bad stuff with my file or my information

Comment: When using a web app be sure to read **ALL** the licence information - it turns out that, according to some high priced lawyers, by uploading to some you are granting **them** copyright and/or publishing your information so they should not be used for proprietary/sensitive information.  Recently had a warning about this at work.  Same for some online translation & photo tools.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Microsoft Power Point Viewer can open any powerpoint (post 1997), including .pptx. [It can be downloaded for free](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=13).

If you right click you can select **Print**.
if you have a PDF printer installed, then you print to PDF and you are done.

There are many good free PDF printers out there.
You can start another question if you have particular intrest in them.
I've use [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) in the past it is quiet good.
I tested this just then using [pdf24](http://en.pdf24.org/), and it worked fine.

Answer (score 8):

**Online Solution. No Software Required.**

Try [**Google Drive**](https://drive.google.com).

Upload your .ppt file to Google Drive. 
Open the file and from the **File** Menu, Select **Download as** where you will find the option of **PDF Document**.
I use this feature a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You should try [Kingsoft Office](http://www.kingsoftstore.com/software/kingsoft-office-freeware). It is known as being more friendly with Office formats than OpenOffice/LibreOffice.

[image]

Another (non free) program that can do this is [Smart Draw](http://www.smartdraw.com/). It's rather expensive and I haven't used it in a while but it always had good quality.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an easy online tool that has no registration or download required, you can try [online2pdf](http://online2pdf.com/convert-ppt-to-pdf). I have used them in the past with no problems whatsoever. I have never found my information to be exposed or abused.

It can convert a variety of document and picture formats to `PDF`, including `pptx`. You can upload multiple files at a time to put a bunch of files into a single `PDF` document.

To convert, simply upload your document you wish to convert, change some settings around if you wish to do so, then click on convert.

The only restriction is that files must be under 50MB and you can only process 100MB of files during one conversion.